# Determining the Total Uncertainty in the Center of a Spectral Line Fit (Physics Experiment)

Tags: curve-fitting, spectral-analysis

Currently I am doing a Physics Experiment that requires fitting spectral lines and the fit I chose was a Voigt Profile. The data that I am fitting has multiple peaks so the fit is the superposition of three separate peaks.

Here is an example of what that looks like:
[image]

I am using a python library I found called [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#voigtmodel) which minimizes the fit and also gives a descriptive report of the parameters and their uncertainties:

```
   # fitting method   = leastsq
   # function evals   = 183
   # data points      = 1200
   # variables        = 10
   chi-square         = 0.25969125
   reduced chi-square = 2.1823e-04
   Akaike info crit   = -10106.0064
   Bayesian info crit = -10055.1056
   [[Variables]]
   D_amplitude:   0.44051227 +/- 0.01786331 (4.06%) (init = 0.537109)
   D_center:      6558.02131 +/- 0.00382755 (0.00%) (init = 6558)
   D_sigma:       0.26938178 +/- 0.00572091 (2.12%) (init = 0.3)
   D_gamma:       0.26938178 +/- 0.00572091 (2.12%) == 'D_sigma'
   D_fwhm:        0.97012209 +/- 0.01252836 (1.29%) == '1.0692*D_gamma+sqrt(0.8664*D_gamma**2+5.545083*D_sigma**2)'
   D_height:      0.34129628 +/- 0.01068745 (3.13%) == '(D_amplitude/(max(2.220446049250313e-16, D_sigma*sqrt(2*pi))))*wofz((1j*D_gamma)/(max(2.220446049250313e-16, D_sigma*sqrt(2)))).real'
   H_amplitude:   0.03513989 +/- 0.00315456 (8.98%) (init = 0.537109)
   H_center:      6559.91608 +/- 0.02088388 (0.00%) (init = 6559.9)
   H_sigma:       0.17161126 +/- 0.01681055 (9.80%) (init = 0.15)
   H_gamma:       0.17161126 +/- 0.01681055 (9.80%) == 'H_sigma'
   H_fwhm:        0.61802204 +/- 0.03681380 (5.96%) == '1.0692*H_gamma+sqrt(0.8664*H_gamma**2+5.545083*H_sigma**2)'
   H_height:      0.04273624 +/- 0.00270988 (6.34%) == '(H_amplitude/(max(2.220446049250313e-16, H_sigma*sqrt(2*pi))))*wofz((1j*H_gamma)/(max(2.220446049250313e-16, H_sigma*sqrt(2)))).real'
   v3_amplitude:  0.38711251 +/- 0.02853380 (7.37%) (init = 0.537109)
   v3_center:     6556.82464 +/- 0.07336412 (0.00%) (init = 6556.1)
   v3_sigma:      0.74169925 +/- 0.03532997 (4.76%) (init = 0.4)
   v3_gamma:      0.74169925 +/- 0.03532997 (4.76%) == 'v3_sigma'
   v3_fwhm:       2.67107458 +/- 0.07736990 (2.90%) == '1.0692*v3_gamma+sqrt(0.8664*v3_gamma**2+5.545083*v3_sigma**2)'
   v3_height:     0.10893091 +/- 0.00575726 (5.29%)
```

I have taken 10 measurements of this exact same spectral line and have used the same fit 10 times. My goal is to record the center of the "H" and "D" peaks and their uncertainties. I am struggling to understand what exactly that reported uncertainty should be.

For example, looking at the "H" peak (green) the uncertainty in the center is about +-0.02. This clearly isn't the uncertainty I should report, correct? To me, it seems way too small. Especially since the error in the other parameters are around 10%.

My question is: How should I report this uncertainty? How can I incorporate the goodness of fit to find the "true" (not sure if this is good wording) uncertainty in one parameter?

If anyone could help out with this or point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. Also, if I am thinking completely wrong about the entire problem, let me know! Thanks for any help!

Comment: `lmfit` is a great choice for this kind of problem. The reported uncertainties look appropriate to me. If you wonder why the error in the peak center is so small, perhaps you could think about how the standard error of the mean scales as you increase the number of samples.

Comment: I can only speculate, so I won't post this as an answer: your intuition that 0.02 is too small looks correct. The problems likely are (1) lack of fit--the possibility of more peaks--and (2) that the estimate of the center is strongly correlated with other estimates, especially its amplitude, its sigma, and the estimates of the D parameters. For a thorough analysis you need to extract the full variance-covariance matrix of the parameter estimates and find how the estimated H center is correlated with its principal components. You can also study the situation through simulation or bootstrapping.

Comment: @whuber The fit report also gives a list of correlations greater than a specified value. I haven't worked this much with statistics before, but from my understanding, the closer the r value is to +- 1, the stronger the correlation, correct? Say, the center of peak D has a correlation equal to 0.9 with the amplitude of peak v3. Then the uncertainty in the amplitude of peak v3 should be included with the uncertainty given in the center? 

Anyway, I need to read up on my own more about correlations. Thanks for the help though.